# Bit order for 2D array

Tags: multidimensional-array, vhdl

I've got a 2x2 array of 4-bit `std_logic_vector` in my VHDL and when I simulate it my tool only gives me a 16 bit `std_logic_vector`, which bits are which?

More generally: how does VHDL store multidimensional arrays?

Comment: Please show the specific type and signal declarations, since this determines the format of the data.  Please also show the output from the simulator.  Note that VHDL is not a programming language where the values are stored in some internal format.

Comment: I've done this in my answer below, am I more or less right or did I miss something?

Comment: Personally I don't see the point in using multidimensional arrays in this form. I find it is much easier to define new types that are arrays of other types that may themselves be array types. In this way you can create totally unambiguous n-dimensional arrays.

Answer (score 0):

From the discussion on this answer it seems that there is no fixed way to store these bits and it's up to the tools you use to provide a correct interface. Mine are apparently a bit wonky.

I did a quick experiment and FOR MY TOOLS it appears the for an array `A` you get the `A(i,j)` in the order you specify them. So if you do:

```
type array_type is array (integer range 0 to 1,integer range 0 to 2) of std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
```

you get: `A(0,0), A(0,1), A(0,...), A(1,0), A(1,1), A(1,...)`.

But if you declare your array as:

```
 type array_type is array (integer range 1 downto 0,integer range 2 downto 0) of std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
```

(Note we're now using `downto`) you'll get `A(1,2), A(1,1), A(1,0), A(0,2), A(1,1), A(0,0)`.

I'm making this deduction based on running the following code:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
entity arrays is
  port (
    x : in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
    y : out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0)
);
end entity arrays;
architecture rtl of arrays is
  type array_type is array (integer range 0 to 1,integer range 0 to 2) of std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
  signal my_array : array_type;
begin
  my_array(0,0) <= "0001";
  my_array(0,1) <= "0010";
  my_array(0,2) <= "0011";
  my_array(1,0) <= "0100";
  my_array(1,1) <= "0101";
  my_array(1,2) <= "0110";
  y <= x;
end architecture rtl;
```

and getting `my_array` to be `123456` where each character is a hex number.
Then I switched round the deceleration and got `654321`.

Comment: Where is `123456` reported? VHDL has no array packing order as far as I know. Reporting array contents is tool specific and compacting all bits to a hexadecimal representation should be considered as false (what if you inner array has 3 instead of 4 bits?).

Comment: the result is the binary version of `123456` so `00010010...` the hex is simply for convenience.

Comment: So is it the case that the array order is left up to the tool vendor? that seems odd

Comment: No it's not, because you can't access the internal representation. Every VHDL tool just needs to assure, that 2,3 is accessing element 2,3. You don't even need to know if x=2/y=3 or x=3/y=2. If you use a binary interface to your simulator e.g. VHPI, there is an API description for data exchange to, let's say, the C++ world. If the simulator uses another internal encoding, it has to translate it, while passing the data through VHPI. A correct tool should not represent an array as a flat string because that's false. Do we talk about Vivado? ... Is usually flattens everything to bits....

Comment: This answer would be more useful if you specified what the tool you are using is.